# O programa só me devolve a lista novamente, sem eu conseguir entrar com os valores, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Tags: c, lógica

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
float saldo, valor;
int opc;


printf("Entre com o saldo inicial da conta: ");
scanf("%f", &saldo);

while (opc != 4)
{
    printf("\nBem vindo ao banco.\n");
    printf("1 - Sacar\n");
    printf("2 - Depositar\n");
    printf("3 - Saldo\n");
    printf("4 - Sair\n");

    printf("Opcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &opc);
}
switch (opc)
{
case 1:
    printf("Valor a sacar: ");
    scanf("%f", &valor);

    saldo = saldo - valor;
    break;

case 2:
    printf("Valor que quer depositar: ");
    scanf("%f", &valor);
    saldo = saldo + valor;
    break;
case 3:
    printf("O saldo atual na conta e: %.2f reais.\n", saldo);
    break;
case 4:
    printf("\nSair\n");
    break;

default:
    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

//Ele deveria me perguntar quanto eu quero sacar/depositar, mas continua apenas me devolvendo a lista de opções. Por exemplo:
Entre com o saldo inicial da conta: 1000   /*Esse é de uma entrada anterior*/
Bem vindo ao banco.
1 - Sacar

2 - Depositar

3 - Saldo

4 - Sair

Opcao:                                 /*E aqui ele repete novamente*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu codigo está correto o problema é o fato do switch está fora do bloco while, é so colocar- lo dentro do while. Da forma como está o codigo so entra no switch quando sai do loop, ou seja quando digita 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  float saldo, valor;
  int opc;
  printf("Entre com o saldo inicial da conta: ");
  scanf("%f", &saldo);

  while (opc != 4)
  {
      printf("\nBem vindo ao banco.\n");
      printf("1 - Sacar\n");
      printf("2 - Depositar\n");
      printf("3 - Saldo\n");
      printf("4 - Sair\n");

      printf("Opcao: ");
      scanf("%d", &opc);

    switch (opc)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Valor a sacar: ");
        scanf("%f", &valor);

        saldo = saldo - valor;
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Valor que quer depositar: ");
        scanf("%f", &valor);
        saldo = saldo + valor;
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("O saldo atual na conta e: %.2f reais.\n", saldo);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("\nSair\n");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```